# React input lose focus when typing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I dont understand why the input loses focus after typing one character when the component is defined inside an other component. I read in other answers to use ref. But it does not work.

Does not work:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


function MyApp() {
  const [text1, setText1] = useState("");
  const [text2, setText2] = useState("");
  const ref1 = useRef(null)
  const ref2 = useRef(null)

  const TextInput = ({ref, text, onChange }) => {
    return <input ref={ref} defaultValue={text} onChange={onChange} />;
  };
  

  const onChange1 = e => {
    setText1(e.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const onChange2 = e => {
    setText2(e.currentTarget.value);
  };
  return (
    <form className="App">
      <TextInput ref={ref1} text={text1} onChange={onChange1} />
      <TextInput ref={ref2} text={text2} onChange={onChange2} />
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, rootElement);
```

When I define the compoent outside everything works fine.

Does work:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


const TextInput = ({ref, text, onChange }) => {
  return <input ref={ref} defaultValue={text} onChange={onChange} />;
};


function MyApp() {
  const [text1, setText1] = useState("");
  const [text2, setText2] = useState("");
  const ref1 = useRef(null)
  const ref2 = useRef(null)



  const onChange1 = e => {
    setText1(e.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const onChange2 = e => {
    setText2(e.currentTarget.value);
  };
  return (
    <form className="App">
      <TextInput ref={ref1} text={text1} onChange={onChange1} />
      <TextInput ref={ref2} text={text2} onChange={onChange2} />
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, rootElement);
```

[JS Fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-1mfix?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Styling a card causes TextField to lose focus in Material UI + React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62624424/styling-a-card-causes-textfield-to-lose-focus-in-material-ui-react)

Answer (score 3):

You are recreating `TextInput` whenever the input value changes and the `MyApp` component renders. If you want to include `TextInput` component inside of `MyApp` component, you can use `useCallback` hook to prevent the recreation of `TextInput` when the component renders.

[JSFiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-wrzfl)

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useCallback } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function MyApp() {
      const [text1, setText1] = useState("");
      const [text2, setText2] = useState("");
      const ref1 = useRef(null);
      const ref2 = useRef(null);

      const TextInput = useCallback(({ ref, text, onChange }) => {
        return <input ref={ref} defaultValue={text} onChange={onChange} />;
      }, []);

      const onChange1 = e => {
        setText1(e.currentTarget.value);
      };

      const onChange2 = e => {
        setText2(e.currentTarget.value);
      };
      return (
        <form className="App">
          <TextInput ref={ref1} text={text1} onChange={onChange1} />
          <TextInput ref={ref2} text={text2} onChange={onChange2} />
        </form>
      );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, rootElement);
```